# AngularJS view not getting updated with model changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Controller (snippet, as its very large):

```
function loadImages() {
    if (Authentication.loggedIn()) {
                Images.get(function(s) {
                    $scope.images = s.images;
                },
                function(f) {} );
    }
}

$scope.loginOnSubmit = function() {
        Authentication.login($scope.model.login).then(
            function(okResponse) {
                    WizardHandler.wizard().next();
                    loadImages()
            },
            function(failureResponse) {
                // TODO: Alert use with the failure
            }
        );
};
loadImages();
```

View:

```
<wz-step title="{{ strings.images.bullet }}">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <h1 ng-bind="strings.images.title"></h1>
            <p ng-bind="strings.images.description"></p>
            <div ui-grid="{ data: images }" class="imagesGrid"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</wz-step>
```

using [angular-wizard](https://github.com/mgonto/angular-wizard) wizard plugin (*wz-step* directive..).
I've looked over the web, thought its related to the $digest, etc.
I've tried using *$timeout(...)* to overcomes this, no go.
what happens is, the data doesnt show up in the view, but when I refresh the page, then its there, or when I even re-size the page, it appears.

Comment: What if you wrap ``$scope.images = s.images;`` inside ``$scope.$apply`` like this:  ``$scope.$apply(function() { $scope.images = s.images; });``? A random shot, a Fiddle would help a lot.

Comment: @tiblu then I get this: $digest already in progress

Comment: Oh. Missed my random. I guess if you create a JSFiddle, it helps others to help you.

Comment: there isn't enough code here to troubleshoot your issue.  for example, do you have other `wz-step`?  The way you describe it, it sounds like this is the first step (data shows on refresh), but you are calling the next step in that code....

Comment: then again, this could be related to this: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/4352, which recommends calling `gridApi.core.refresh() ;` if the data bound to the `ui-grid` changes.